# Alter DIV on Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to have a series of yes/no questions, & depending on the RADIO BUTTON, the answer / text appears on the appropriate DIV.

I have found one answer - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/XFKLC/) and this does what i am after.

My question is, how easy is it to alter this so I can have MULTIPLE sets of radio buttons.

Ie

```
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="tuser1" id="tuser1" /> (question 1)
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="tuser2" id="tuser2" /> (question 2)
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="tuser3" id="tuser3" /> (question 3) etc.
```

is it easy to alter the function, to accept numeric references & to alter the approriate DIV set ?

PS - i assume i can have text of multiple lines/paragraphs in each DIV.

PPS: my ultimate aim is to combine the "visable" divs, into a master div underneath (with a blank line in each div reply).

IE,

Q1 (yes/no),    (show answer to q1 "yes")/(show answer to q1 "no")

master div:-

show Q1 result.

show Q2 result.

show Q3 result.

etc...

i'll put the master div inside a TEXTAREA form - to send to another website for processing - on my server.

i want the master div to preserve any new-lines / formattng of the answers (if the answer is on several lines).

Comment: I don't quite get this.

Comment: So, each question have a yes/no radio button set. right?

Comment: yes - Ive seen examples with ONE question (2 or more answers). However i cannnot find examples with multiple questions (change the 2nd answer does not alter the answer to question 1).

Comment: if i have 15, 20 or more questions, i would not want 15, 20 different functions (one for each set of questions/answer). i'm looking for a way to have multiple sets of questions (& divs), but one function.

Comment: @sarah I posted my answer below... let me know, if you need any additional functions.

Comment: i've4 adjusted the script a bit - & get interesting results. http://pastebin.com/r9aY3RDE  (Clicxk on the results area & you'll get the result.) i'll play around with it tomorrow. i see that its taking the WHOLe div of each question. I'll only want results.

Comment: no worries, i'll post another stackoverflow query tomorrow, after i've played around with the script.

Comment: I'm happy i'm happy.

i've found the best result to what i want. adding a new sub-class, I can now display the results in my combined DIV.

http://pastebin.com/WNRm4nfu

Comment: @sarah well... good...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your each question set in `div`. By this you can easily group your question. You can use `class` and `data` attributes.

Try this code,

**HTML :**

```
<div id="Qset1">
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" data-id="yes" value="deliverer" name="type" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="type" data-id="No" value="tuser" id="tuser" />
    <div id='optuser' class="yes">//some input fields1</div>
    <div id='optdeliverer' class="no">//some other input fields1</div>
</div>
<div id="Qset2">
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" data-id="yes" value="deliverer" name="type2" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="type2" data-id="No" value="tuser" id="tuser" />
    <div id='optuser' class="yes">//some input fields2</div>
    <div id='optdeliverer' class="no">//some other input fields2</div>
</div>
<div id="Qset3">
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" data-id="yes" value="deliverer" name="type3" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="type3" data-id="No" value="tuser" id="tuser" />
    <div id='optuser' class="yes">//some input fields3</div>
    <div id='optdeliverer' class="no">//some other input fields3</div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-id', 'yes').is(':checked')) $(this).closest('div').find('.yes').toggle();
        if ($(this).attr('data-id', 'no').is(':checked')) $(this).closest('div').find('.no').toggle();
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/RF6F7/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.. & i've even preserved the linebreaks.  -#optdeliverer { display: none;    white-space: pre; }

Comment: Ps, ive found 1 error, but thats not a big deal. (click the "no" options 2-3-4 times. the text still changes on each click -  not depending on WHICH option you click.  Not a big deal - i can live with it & use the code.

Comment: @sarah use `change` event listener instead of `click` event listener. I updated my answer. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/X5ERV/) find here

1. Remove checked property from radio buttons
2. I have add parent div for wrap questions called questions
3. Named textarea id as answers

**HTML**

```
<div id="questions">
<div id="Qset1">Question number 1
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" data-id="yes" value="deliverer" name="type"  />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="type" data-id="No" value="tuser" id="tuser" />No
   </div>
<div id="Qset2">Question number 2
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" data-id="yes" value="deliverer" name="type2"  />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="type2" data-id="No" value="tuser" id="tuser" />No
</div>
<div id="Qset3">Question number 3
    <input type="radio" id="deliverer" data-id="yes" value="deliverer" name="type3"  />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="type3" data-id="No" value="tuser" id="tuser" />No
</div>
</div>

<textarea id="answers"></textarea>
```

**Added some css**

```
#questions,#answers{
    width:200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#answers{
    border:1px soied #000;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}
```

**Here is the Jquery**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {

        var ans="";
        $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){

            if($(this).attr("checked"))
               {
              var question=$(this).parent().contents().get(0).nodeValue;
               ans=ans + question + $(this).val() + "\r" ;

                }

               $("#answers").html(ans);
        });

    });
});
```